# Sum multiple selects between time range in a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a MySQL query. I'm trying to create a multi query that selects the sum() over a time range. e.g. first select is the sum over the last 1 hour period, second the sum between 1 hour and 2 hours, third the sum between 2 hours and 3 hours, forth the sum between 3 hours and 4 hours, five the sum between 4 hours and 5 hours.

After I want to do some math with each result and store it in an array. I've tried UNION and UNION ALL but can't use a unique name for each select so it results in each array element being the same result. I can't seem to figure out the query that'll produce the desired results. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

```
CREATE TABLE `numbers` (
  `id` int(id) NOT NULL,
  `inserttime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `number` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
)

select distinct sum(number) as xyz from `numbers` where inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 60 minute)) 
    UNION select sum(number) as zyx from `numbers` where inserttime >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 60 minute)) and inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 120 minute)) 
    UNION select sum(number) as yzx from `numbers` where inserttime >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 120 minute)) and inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 180 minute)) 
    UNION select sum(number) as yxz from `numbers` where inserttime >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 180 minute)) and inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 240 minute)) 
    UNION select sum(number) as zxy from `numbers` where inserttime >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 240 minute)) and inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 300 minute))
```

Also tried the following but it doesn't work either, I don't think the code is correct.

```
SELECT number, SUM(IF(inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 60 minute)))) AS oneHour,
       SUM(IF(inserttime >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 60 minute)) and inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 120 minute)))) AS twoHour,
       SUM(IF(inserttime >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 120 minute)) and inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 180 minute)))) AS threeHour,
       SUM(IF(inserttime >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 180 minute)) and inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 240 minute)))) AS fourHour,
       SUM(IF(inserttime >= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 240 minute)) and inserttime <= timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 300 minute)))) AS fiveHour  
       FROM `numbers` GROUP BY timestamp
```

Desired result

```
[{"number":"14.56"},{"number":"15.68"},{"number":"20.00"},{"number":"10.00"},{"number":"33.04"}]
```

Third attempt results in repeated values 21.47,21.47,21.47,21.47,21.47 or  `[{"oneHour":"229376","twoHour":"0","threeHour":"0","fourHour":"0","fiveHour":"0"}]` as response depending on how I get the results

```
SELECT CASE WHEN inserttime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE AND NOW() THEN SUM(number) ELSE 0 END AS oneHour,
CASE WHEN inserttime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 120 MINUTE AND NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE THEN SUM(number) ELSE 0 END AS twoHour,
CASE WHEN inserttime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 180 MINUTE AND NOW() - INTERVAL 120 MINUTE THEN SUM(number) ELSE 0 END AS threeHour,
CASE WHEN inserttime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 240 MINUTE AND NOW() - INTERVAL 180 MINUTE THEN SUM(number) ELSE 0 END AS fourHour,
CASE WHEN inserttime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 300 MINUTE AND NOW() - INTERVAL 240 MINUTE THEN SUM(number) ELSE 0 END AS fiveHour
FROM `numbers` WHERE inserttime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 300 MINUTE AND NOW()
```

Comment: When I run that second attempt ^^ it returns nothing so I assume its an issue with the conditions because there is definitely results within those periods. Any ideas ??

Comment: Post SQL code only, remove PHP wrapping. Provide sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts) which must give "Desired result".

Comment: `timestamp` is reserved word, so both queries must produce syntax error.

Comment: No it doesn't produce an error. I use timestamp in the same way with other queries and works without issue.

Comment: Also it's not the desired result I am worried about. I am curious as to if the second query is written correctly. If I can create the correct query I can format to get desired results.

Comment: You're lucky... nevertheless 2nd query is synthactically wrong - you try to use IF() with one argument whereas it needs 3 ones.

Comment: First, you want `>= and <` rather than `>= and <=` or `between`. Using either of the latter two patterns means that each hour boundary is included in two different time ranges.  Second, you should create some example data that demonstrates under what conditions your problem arises. If you can't replicate the problem with example data then you're not providing us with enough information to solve it for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next pattern:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN ts BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE 
                             AND NOW() 
                 THEN val 
                 ELSE 0 
                 END ) sum_0_60,
       SUM( CASE WHEN ts BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 120 MINUTE 
                             AND NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE 
                 THEN val 
                 ELSE 0 
                 END ) sum_60_120,
       .......
FROM table 
WHERE ts BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 300 MINUTE AND NOW()
```

Comment: 21.47,21.47,21.47,21.47,21.47 repeats the same result in each element even though each sum should produce different results. Something isn't right again with the condition

Comment: that or [{"oneHour":"229376","twoHour":"0","threeHour":"0","fourHour":"0","fiveHour":"0"}] depending

Comment: @unknown1 Your third query (which you just added to your question) is NOT the same as this answer. You have `CASE WHEN x THEN SUM(y) END` but this answer is clearly `SUM(CASE WHEN x THEN y END)`

Comment: @unknown1 The answer is completely clear. You have the CASE expression ***outside*** of the SUM, this answer has the CASE expression ***inside*** of the SUM.  In this answer the CASE checks each row one at a time, this means that some rows contribute `val` to the aggregate, and other rows contribute `0`. In your code you ***always*** SUM() ***all*** of the rows, regardless of the condition, and THEN apply a check as to whether to show the niave SUM() or 0. That's fundamentally different. Even if you don't understand why, Try It As Actually Written.

Comment: Indeed! It's working. ^^ as written by example

Comment: Next time, please THINK before claiming an answer doesn't work. If you changed the code, Your Change may well be the cause of the failure.